# What is the best way to add checkbox content to a collection in PowerApps?

Tags: powerapps

I have 12 checkboxes each with a trait associated with them. I'd like to program their OnCheck so that when each is clicked, the associated trait is added to a collection. There will be a later button which adds the list of selected traits to a SharePoint List, and this button is programmed, but I can't get the checkbox/collection to work right.

I additionally would like to program the OnUncheck to remove from the collection.

For OnCheck, I tried:

```
Collect(CBI_DR_PosCol, CBI_DR_Positive_1.Value)
```

This only adds "true" to the collection though. I tried replacing .Value with .Text, but this was an error.

EDIT: The error reads: "The function 'Collect' has some invalid arguments."

For OnUncheck, I tried:

```
RemoveIf(CBI_DR_PosCol, "Trait1" = CBI_DR_Positive_1.Text)
```

and this seemed to work.

Comment: I think more info is needed to fully understand what you are fighting with. What was the error message for the .Text variant of your formula? Are you storing the 'traits' as separate rows in SharePoint or as choices in a Choice field for a single row? Is the checkbox .Text a dynamic value?

Comment: @mmikesy90 I edited the main post to reflect the error. The error reads: "The function 'Collect' has some invalid arguments."

I'd like the traits to be stored in a cell in a SharePoint list. For example, a user will select a candidate from a dropdown, then click the traits that apply. In the sharepoint list will be a row for each candidate, then a column for each section, one of which will be a list of the traits here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments and the edited question:

To store traits in a Choice field for each candidate (row), you should represent traits in Power Apps like records: `{ Value: "Trait1" }`. This is something that SharePoint accepts and you can use the collection's .Value property in the checkboxes.

If the checkboxes are in a gallery, .Text should be `ThisItem.Value`

The formulas need to be updated too:

```
Collect(CBI_DR_PosCol, { Value: Self.Value })

RemoveIf(CBI_DR_PosCol, Value = Self.Text)
```